# rosdep: command not found

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to install RGBDSLAM on Ubuntu 11.10

I installed Ros Fuerte because Octomap viz isn't available as a package for Ros Electric.

One of the steps it asks for is to resolve dependencies using rosdep.
However, whenever I issue rosdep I get "command not found".

Most other commands work perfectly. Here is the output from a `ros[tab][tab]`

```
~/ros_workspace/fuerte$ ros

*rosawesome      rosed           rosmsg          rosstack
rosbag          rosgraph        rosmsg-proto    rostest
rosboost-cfg    rosinstall      rosnode         rostopic
rosclean        roslaunch-deps  rosparam        rosversion
rosco           roslaunch-logs  rospd           rosws
roscore         roslocate       rospython       roswtf
roscp           rosls           rosrun          
roscreate-pkg   rosmake         rosservice      
rosd            rosmaster       rossrv*
```

I have messed around with environment variables to the point that I believe that is not the issue. Here goes an env | grep ROS

```
*ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/vittorio/ros_workspace/fuerte:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/vittorio/ros_workspace/fuerte
ROS_PARALLEL_JOBS=-j4
ROS_DISTRO=fuerte
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/fuerte/etc/ros*
```

Here goes a echo $PATH and echo $PYTHONPATH

```
echo $PATH
*/opt/ros/fuerte/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games*

echo $PYTHONPATH
*/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:*
```

I am curious as to why there is a colon at the end of dist-packages. There is one colon at the end of the statement in /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh , but I believe that one should disappear when the environment variable gets passed.

Any other ideas as to why rosdep doesn't work in fuerte?

P.S. I can switch my environment back to electric, and rosdep works.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32875/rosdep:-command-not-found/) by [Vittorio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/2132/vittorio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte introduces a new `rosdep` implementation, which must be installed via `pip`, separately from the ROS distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U rosdep
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

See: [REP-0125](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0125.html).

UPDATE: people building ROS packages from source may want to install these Python packages, too:

```
sudo pip install -U rosinstall vcstools rospkg
```

UPDATE2: instead of using `pip`, the recommended install method on Ubuntu is now:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

The init and update steps are still necessary.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vittorio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/2132/vittorio88/) on 2012-04-30**:
Thank you very much!! That did the trick. Is there any other standard ROS programs from electric that you are aware of that also require an installation from pip? Rosdep should be installed with the standard apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full.BTW does that car from Austinrobot.com also run ROS?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-01**:
Yes, our autonomous vehicle now runs ROS.